# EF Code First: Migrating Database Initialized on Different Code Versions

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 RC, code first. I am struggling with migrating databases that were created on different versions of code. For example, Database A was created when table FooBar didn't exist. Database B was created after table FooBar was added to my model.

I have a migration written that adds the FooBar table. Is it my responsibility to check in the FooBar migration that the table doesn't exist before calling CreateTable? It seems that is the case since Database B doesn't have an entry for the FooBar migration and will attempt to run it.

At first the MigrationHistory table seemed like it would save me from adding these checks but since new databases won't have entries for migrations added before the database was created, I still need to do the checks myself. Is that the right way to go about it or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To get around an issue I had with adding Stored Procedures, I wrote a TSQL script to create a new table "_*PreviousMigrationHistory" - which receives new entries from the "*_MigrationHistory" table after my stored procedure scripts have run...

I did add a new column to both tables ( "VersionId", of INT - IDENTITY(1,1) ) which is what I use for comparison within my code.

This way you have the un-updated migration patterns available to you (__PreviousMigrationHistory), even after Code First Migrations have occurred.

Would this help?

**EDIT -  sorry, I miss read the question. - Although I would think that new instances of the database would still go through the migration steps, which in turn should add the entries to the __MigrationHistory table?